# JSON Schema make property conditionally required

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

My current JSON schema definition is like this

```
{
  "properties": {
    "account_type": {
      "description": "account type",
      "enum": [
        "CURRENT",
        "SAVINGS",
        "DEMAT"
      ],
      "type": "string"
    },
    "demat_account_number": {
      "description": "demat_account_number",
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "account_type"
  ],
  "type": "object"
}
```

My requirement is if "account_type" = "DEMAT" then "demat_account_number" should become a required attribute.

Is there any way we can achieve this validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "oneOf". This forces conforming documents to implement only one of a number of possible patterns:

```
{
    "oneOf":[
        {
            "properties":{
                "account_type":{
                    "description":"account type",
                    "enum":[
                        "CURRENT",
                        "SAVINGS"
                    ],
                    "type":"string"
                }
            },
            "required":[
                "account_type"
            ],
            "type":"object"
        },
        {
            "properties":{
                "account_type":{
                    "description":"account type",
                    "enum":[
                        "DEMAT"
                    ],
                    "type":"string"
                },
                "demat_account_number":{
                    "description":"demat_account_number",
                    "type":"string"
                }
            },
            "required":[
                "account_type",
                "demat_account_number"
            ],
            "type":"object"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Works...Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

A nice option is to use a `if`/`then`. The `if` block uses the `const` assertion to verify that `account_type` has the `"DEMAT"` value. The `then` block adds the `demat_account_number` to the `required` properties.

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "account_type": {
    },
    "demat_account_number": {
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "account_type"
  ],
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "account_type": {
        "const": "DEMAT"
      }
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "required": [
      "demat_account_number"
    ]
  }
}
```